# In Openoffice, Calc, to index areas under condition, between two words

Tags: formula, openoffice-calc, array-formulas

In Openoffice, Calc, to index areas under condition, between two e.g. words?

E.g. in a column A, one under another "A,B,D,c,A,B,C,A,C)...
I want each time to index only A to C, and when results are reported with Match functions (of corresponding column B values), to continue to the next region AC. How can i do this in #Calc?

1rst region:ABDC,
2nd:ABC,
3rd:AC

Answer (score 0):

In cell B1 enter `1`, then in cell B2 enter `=IF(A2="A";B1+1;B1)`

Copy cell B2 and paste down however many rows your pattern is.  Calc will automatically adjust the formula to increase the row numbers as you paste in lower rows.  This formula will go up by 1 whenever the pattern has an `A`, otherwise it will repeat the number from the previous row.

Note that it is case-sensitive and will not increment for `a`. If you want either case (`A` or `a`) to trigger the increment, use `=IF(OR(A2="A";A2="a");B1+1;B1)`

Comment: My example was simple enough, i had a more complex task to make. Thanks anyway!